# How to make 2 different scroll functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, scroll

Hello I made 2 scripts for scrolling, one make navbar smaller second one show the button for going on start of page. When I added second one (for button) my first one for navbar didn't work. I deleted second one and it worked. What I need to change?

**For navbar**

```
        window.onscroll = function() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0];
  var className = 'small';
  if (el.classList) {
    if (window.scrollY > 10)
      el.classList.add(className);
    else
      el.classList.remove(className);
  }
};

        window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
    var scrollContainer = target;
    do { //find scroll container
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

    var targetY = 0;
    do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
        if (target == scrollContainer) break;
        targetY += target.offsetTop;
    } while (target = target.offsetParent);

    scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {
        i++; if (i > 30) return;
        c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
        setTimeout(function(){ scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 20);
    }
    // start scrolling
    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
}
```

**For button**

```
//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll1 = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
     <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>  
        
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: oh I forgot it,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the second `window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};` from your button and add the  `scrollFunction();` in your navbar `window.onscroll`, your initial code had a extra 1 at the `window.onscroll1` but you don't need to set it twice, test it out, I've added some CSS so the button stay at the bottom right and some height to test scrolling

```js
window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction();
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0];
  var className = "small";
  if (el.classList) {
    if (window.scrollY > 10) el.classList.add(className);
    else el.classList.remove(className);
  }
};

window.smoothScroll = function (target) {
  var scrollContainer = target;
  do {
    //find scroll container
    scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
    if (!scrollContainer) return;
    scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
  } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

  var targetY = 0;
  do {
    //find the top of target relatively to the container
    if (target == scrollContainer) break;
    targetY += target.offsetTop;
  } while ((target = target.offsetParent));

  scroll = function (c, a, b, i) {
    i++;
    if (i > 30) return;
    c.scrollTop = a + ((b - a) / 30) * i;
    setTimeout(function () {
      scroll(c, a, b, i);
    }, 20);
  };
  // start scrolling
  scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
};

//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
//window.onscroll1 = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 1999px;
}
#myBtn  {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working, I decided to use yours.

Answer (score 0):

**I found another solution**

Something like this

```
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    
        window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};{
  function scrollFunction() {
        var el = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0];
  // Vrh button prikazivanje
  var className = 'small';
  if (el.classList) {
    if (window.scrollY > 10)
      el.classList.add(className);
    else
      el.classList.remove(className);
  }
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}
};

        window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
    var scrollContainer = target;
    do { //find scroll container
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

    var targetY = 0;
    do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
        if (target == scrollContainer) break;
        targetY += target.offsetTop;
    } while (target = target.offsetParent);

    scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {
        i++; if (i > 30) return;
        c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
        setTimeout(function(){ scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 20);
    }
    // start scrolling
    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
}
```